# Run excel macro code recursively on all files inside of a folder and subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, recursion

I have a folder where I have many sub-folders and inside of them more than 1000 Excel files.

I want to run a specific macro (that changes a workbook) on all these files.

Already saw the following answer.

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\C:\...\EXCL\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        DoWork wb
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    With wb
        'Do your work here
        ......
    End With
End Sub
```

There are two problems:
1. this will be extremely slow. Is there a faster way?
2. this will only run on the files in the matching folder and not the files in all sub-folders. Is there way to do that for files in sub-folders as well?

Comment: try writing a VBScript

Comment: @ShaiRado you say that VBScript is better because it's more fast?

Comment: yes, but not only, it's more suitable for tasks involving multiple folders and files.

Comment: @ShaiRado well I'm not so familiar with VBscript.. is that something complex to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, VBA can't edit closet workbook. If you want to do work for every workbook in every subfolder, subfolder of subfolder etc. you can use the following code. I added condition, that it have to be `.xlsx` file, you can change it on `.xls`, `.xlsb` or whatever you want.

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim MyPath As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo EmptyEnd
        MyPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Call GetAllFiles(MyPath, objFSO)
    Call GetAllFolders(MyPath, objFSO)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Complete."

EmptyEnd:
End Sub

Sub GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, ByRef objFSO As Object)
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            DoWork objFile.Path
    Next objFile
End Sub

Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, ByRef objFSO As Object)
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        Call GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO)
        Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO)
    Next objSubFolder
End Sub

Sub DoWork(strFile As String)
Dim wb As Workbook
    If Right(strFile, 4) = "xlsx" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFile)
        With wb
            'Do your work here
            ......
            .Close True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is this?

Comment: when running following code i revived : run-time error '1004': Sorry, we couldn't find. Is It possible it was moved, renamed or deleted? and actually when I'm in debugging mode i see MyPath and MyFile is both empty on sub Dowork in line: " Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & MyFile)"

Comment: when I'm thinking about it : how could it works if it's on other method, i mean for example :'MyPath' defined in 'ProcessFiles' so it won't be defined in 'Dowork' method...

Answer (score 2):

If I get this right you need a function which collects all xl files in a directory and subdirs. This function will do that:

```
Public Function RecursiveDir(colFiles As Collection, _
                             strFolder As String, _
                             strFileSpec As String, _
                             bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim vFolderName As Variant

    'Add files in strFolder matching strFileSpec to colFiles
    strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
    strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)
    Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
        colFiles.Add strFolder & strTemp
        strTemp = Dir
    Loop

    If bIncludeSubfolders Then
        'Fill colFolders with list of subdirectories of strFolder
        strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)
        Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
            If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
                If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                    colFolders.Add strTemp
                End If
            End If
            strTemp = Dir
        Loop

        'Call RecursiveDir for each subfolder in colFolders
        For Each vFolderName In colFolders
            Call RecursiveDir(colFiles, strFolder & vFolderName, strFileSpec, True)
        Next vFolderName
    End If

End Function


Public Function TrailingSlash(strFolder As String) As String
    If Len(strFolder) > 0 Then
        If Right(strFolder, 1) = "\" Then
            TrailingSlash = strFolder
        Else
            TrailingSlash = strFolder & "\"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

And this shows how to use it

```
Sub TesterFiles()

Dim colFiles As New Collection

    RecursiveDir colFiles, "Your Dir goes here...", "*.XLS*", True

    Dim vFile As Variant
    For Each vFile In colFiles
        ' Do sth with the file
        Debug.Print vFile
    Next vFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice one Storax!  I would use the script that Storax posted, and modify it just a tad.

```
i = 1
Dim vFile As Variant
For Each vFile In colFiles
    ' Do sth with the file
    Range("A" & i).Value = vFile
    i = i + 1
Next vFile
```

I think it's just easier to work with a list.  Anyway, once you have the file structure, you can run through those elements in the array you just created.  Use the script below to do that.

```
Sub LoopThroughRange()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A13")

For Each cell In rng

        'For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(cell)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then


                'Change cell value(s) in one worksheet in mybook
                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    If .ProtectContents = False Then
                        .Range("A1").Value = "My New Header"
                    Else
                        ErrorYes = True
                    End If
                End With


                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrorYes = True
                    Err.Clear
                    'Close mybook without saving
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                Else
                    'Save and close mybook
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=True
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                'Not possible to open the workbook
                ErrorYes = True
            End If

        'Next Fnum

Next cell

End Sub
```

The idea comes straight from here.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win010.htm

**Pay attention to this part:
'Change cell value(s) in one worksheet in mybook
That's where you want to put specific your code to do exactly what you want to do.**

I just modified my OP.  It's a lot easier, and a little different, than I initially made it out to be.  I've adjusted the script accordingly.